# Why is CS4014 not shown for all functions that return a task?

Tags: c#, async-await

Suppose the following code:

```
private async Task Test1Async() => await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
private Task Test2Async() => Test1Async();
```

Functionally, these functions are exactly the same but the compiler treats calling these methods different. The following code compiles, but issues a CS4014 warning:

```
private void Test() => Test1Async();   // CS4014 is shown
```

It generates the warning "*because this call is not awaited, the current method continues to run before the call is completed*". This is a proper warning, because it often indicates a flaw in your code. In case you actually want this behavior, then you can solve it by using the following code:

```
private void Test() => _ = Test1Async();   // CS4014 is not shown anymore
```

Assigning the value to `_` is a relative new feature to indicate that the value is ignored intentionally.

This code doesn't raise CS4014:

```
private void Test() => Test2Async();   // CS4014 is not shown!
```

Of course, I could rewrite all my methods to use the `async/await` method, but this results in more code that runs less efficient (due to the state machine generated by the `async` keyword). Maybe I will never forget about it, but my coworkers might and then I won't get a trigger (or I call a third-party library that doesn't use async).

There is also a difference in the warning about the returned Task usage.

Does anyone know why this warning is not generated for methods that return a `Task` that don't use the `async` keyword?

Comment: It is hidden in the syntax sugar.  The assignment ensures that the Task.Result property gets evaluated.  Which ensures that the task is completed.  Too much sugar does cause tooth decay.

Comment: @HansPassant Which Task.Result property? Does a simple Task (no generic) has any Result property?

Comment: The second case: `Test2Async()` is not marked `async`, so this method _itself_ is not considered as "continue[ing] to run before the call is completed". And it indeed does not, this method is fully completed when it returns. It's `Test1Async()` that "keeps running".

Comment: my goolge seems broken, can you show me a link to docs/specs for this `_ = Test1Async()` construct? Is this c#7 or 6, I can't find it. Does it have a name?

Comment: @RenéVogt: mentioned here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/; search the page for "discard".

Comment: @RenéVogt Here a [.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/COfrcj) - all running in async

Comment: @SirRufo I don't know if you posted this to prove me wrong... you did not. My point was, that if `Test2Async()` would contain more calls than the one to `Test1Async()`, all these calls would be completed before `Test2Async()` returns to `Test`. The fact that the inner `Test1Async()` is not completed is not relevant for CS4014. `Test2Async()` is not `async` it just returns a `Task`. An `async` method like `Test1Async()` returns a `Task` _that represents the continuation, the rest of this method still to do_. That's the difference.

Comment: @RenéVogt The code *Task Task2Async() => Task1Async();* is exactly the same as *Task Task2Async() { return Task1Async(); }* - The Task will be processed, because it will only return the Task from Task1Async

Comment: @RenéVogt But you are right, the Task2Async method will not create another Task, but that is obvious

Comment: @RenéVogt I agree that it doesn't create a task of its own, but with optimizations enabled, the `Test2Async` will probably disappear and the compiler will call `Test1Async` directly. So both calls are 100% identical, but the `async` variant will issue a warning, where the other doesn't. It seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this warning is not generated for methods that return a `Task` that don't use the `async` keyword?

Probably to avoid spurious warnings on legacy code. `Task` predated `async`, and there's a number of methods out there that return `Task` but don't have anything to do with asynchronous code.

Personally, I think ignoring a `Task` return value is almost certainly a mistake, even in non-asynchronous code. But I assume that the MS team ran metrics and determined this warning would be too noisy for those kinds of code bases.

Comment: I think ignoring a `Task` is worth generating CS4014 in both cases and it would seem more consistent. It's a warning, so enabling it for both styles wouldn't actually break anything. I always thought that the `async` keyword was syntactical sugar that generated the complex state-machine under the hood. But the end-result is just a normal function returning a `Task`. That's why I would think that it should be handled the same. As far as I know TPL was introduced in .NET 4 and the async keyword was introced in the .NET 4.5 era...

Comment: I have submitted an issue with the Roslyn team for this issue (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/21428). Hope they can clarify or fix this...

Comment: You were right. See this comment from the Roslyn team:
 https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20782#issuecomment-316764474: "This behavior is "By Design". The compiler will only issue CS4014 for explicitly marked async methods. Having it issue the warning for all methods that return Task is a significant compat break."

Comment: I just tracked a bug on this and I'm realizing now that calling async methods via an interface doesn't seem to trigger CS4014. That's pretty terrible. Everything is marked async. Everything returns a task, but no CS4014 when called via an interface presumably because you can't mark interface methods as async. Is this right?

Comment: @Skrymsli: the interface *implementation* can (and presumably should) be `async`.

Answer (score -1):

The warning isn't issued because no `Task` is dropped on the floor.  The `Task` is being returned, so the caller is entirely capable of observing it.  The warning exists to point out tasks that are not being observed.  It would be *wrong* to produce a warning.

The code is correct; producing a warning for *correct* code is very problematic, as it's likely to result in the programmer changing it into incorrect code, worse code, confusion on there part as to what the problem is (because there isn't one) or, at the very least, them needing to spend extra work to work around a bad warning.

Comment: Both methods return a task and you're right. It is indeed the responsibility of the caller to do something with the task. Warnings are there to indicate possible problems in your code. Ignoring tasks (silently) is such a potential problem, so it would be good to produce a warning. C# 7 has an excellent way (_) to indicate that you want to ignore a result.